# Django cannot call migrate after makemigrations utilizing call_command

Tags: django

I am using django 1.11 on python 3.6.

The easiest way I can explain my problem is that I am creating a test database on the fly in my code. I do this with the following script:

```
from uuid import uuid4 as uuid
db = '_' + uuid().hex + 'db.sqlite3'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_TEST_DB_NAME', db)
print(db)

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django.setup()

print("Setting up test database\n")

print("Clearing migrations...\n")
_dir = os.getcwd()
_search = ['project', 'email_auth', 'google', 'app2', 'app3']
for _d in _search:
    _walk = os.walk(_dir + os.path.sep + _d)
    for _walkObj in _walk:
        if _walkObj[0].split(os.path.sep)[-1] == 'migrations' or \
                (_walkObj[0].split(os.path.sep)[-2] == 'migrations' 
                and _walkObj[0].split(os.path.sep)[-1] == '__pycache__'):
            for _fName in _walkObj[2]:
                os.remove(_walkObj[0] + os.path.sep + _fName)

print("Calling manage:makemigrations\n")
call_command('makemigrations', *_search[1:])

apps.clear_cache()
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

print("Calling manage:migrate...\n")
call_command('migrate')

print("Creating objects...\n")
call_command('create_objects')

print("Starting server...\n")
call_command('runserver')
```

No matter what I do to the apps object (I tried some hacky things to clear out everything inside of it to reload, but no dice) or anything else I cannot get django to realize that there are migrations created for any of my apps when calling migrate.

I have even attempted just calling into migrate, email_auth and it states that `django.core.management.base.CommandError: App 'email_auth' does not have migrations.`

I can call migrate outside of this script if I cancel it after the makemigrations portion and it migrates just fine.

I strongly suspect it's not working because somewhere django has the old references to the modules and I have no idea how to update them.

Edit:

Just so there is proof that it is indeed migrating, I uploaded a paste bin of console output: https://pastebin.com/aSructTW

Comment: If you need a test database why not have a different settings file for that? Best practice is to have a base/local/test/staging/prod settings file. Also you are not supposed to remove migrations from third party library, if you need something custom fork the library and use that in your requirments file.

Comment: This isn't for just one test database, this is for generating test databases on the fly. It's completely doable and working, the only portion that isn't working is running migrate right after makemigrations because the modules need reloading. Also, I am not removing migrations from any third party libraries? Those are ones that I have created myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this properly. Please note that there is more to getting the test database to be created/used, however this question's scope is for reloading the apps. If anyone wants code for that let me know. Here is the function to clear out apps:

```
def resetApps(search=[]):
    from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
    import os
    import sys
    from django.apps import apps
    from django.conf import settings

    apps.clear_cache()
    apps.all_models = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
    apps.app_configs = OrderedDict()
    apps.stored_app_configs = []
    apps.apps_ready = apps.models_ready = apps.ready = False
    apps._pending_operations = defaultdict(list)
    # clear out py caches of apps as we need to reload
    # modify this to allow removal of .pyc files that aren't in pycache, btw
    for _d in search:
        _walk = os.walk(_dir + os.path.sep + _d)
        for _walkObj in _walk:
            if _walkObj[0].split(os.path.sep)[-1] == '__pycache__':
                for _fName in _walkObj[2]:
                    os.remove(_walkObj[0] + os.path.sep + _fName)
    # clear out sys modules of required things
    _toClear = []
    for module in sys.modules:
        if module.split('.')[0] in search:
            _toClear.append(module)
    for module in _toClear:
        del sys.modules[module]
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```